# VBA Save a copy of a file then open it

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save a copy of a file, then open the copy (ActiveName is declared earlier as the name of the active workbook.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & PCusername & "\Desktop\Folder\" & ActiveName & "_NEW.xlsx"
   
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\" & PCusername & "\Desktop\Folder\" & ActiveName & "_NEW")
```

The copy is saved, but then I get the error message when trying to open:
Runtime error 1004
Excel cannot open the file *ActiveName*.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid.

Comment: My guess: are you trying to change the extension when saving a copy? If so, you can't do that.

Comment: Or forgot to add the extension after `"_NEW"`? Change it to `"_NEW.xlsx"`

Comment: @BigBen. Thank you. The workbook I have open is the one I'm running the macro from (.xlsm). It seems to save  a copy as .xlsx file OK (removal of macros, which is fine). But it just won't open. Is there a better way of saving so it can be opened as an .xlsx file?

Comment: @Sam I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately I'm still coming up with the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: "it just won't open" - what happens when you try to open it?

Comment: you cannot change the file format when using SaveCopyAs. Your new file is internaly a xlsm file with a xlsx extension, hence the error

Comment: Either use SaveCopyAs with the same extension, or SaveAs if you need to change the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Dim p, wb As Workbook 

p = "C:\Users\" & PCusername & "\Desktop\Folder\" & _
     Replace(ThisWorkBook.Name,".xlsm", "_NEW.xlsm")

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs p
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(p)
'here you can SaveAs with `wb` if you want to change to xlsx...
```

Note that `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where your VBA is running - safer to use that in place of `ActiveWorkbook`