# How do you make VBA document open a copy of itself in a folder every time you open it?

Tags: excel, vba

When you run this program it opens a csv file in the allocated folder. What should i write in this code for when i open the file it makes a copy?

```
Open "C:\raspbbbb\users.csv" For Output As #1
i = 2
Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
myStr = ""
For j = 9 To 10
myStr = myStr & Cells(i, j) & "; "
Next
Print #1, myStr
i = i + 1
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

I tried changing the output and close types but that just makes it crash

Comment: This maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69090256/vba-save-a-copy-of-a-file-then-open-it

Answer (score 1):

In the code module for `ThisWorkbook`, create an event script for `Workbook_Open`:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim CopyName As String
    CopyName = Split(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".")(0) & " Copy." & Split(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".")(1)
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & CopyName
End Sub
```

Save the file as a Macro Enabled Workbook, `xlsm`. Now when you open the workbook, it will create a copy of itself in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could possibly rephrase the question as it is not too clear what you are trying to achieve, and what is then going wrong?
Many thanks.

Comment: Yes so basically i want/need for the program to make it where if i open the csv file manually through the folder, a copy is made. And when i open it again another copy is made. Maybe that is not even possible but im pretty sure it is.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment. Please do not add comments as answers. If you lack the reputation to make a comment, then please earn that reputation first.